# How can I use two linked tables with similar columns to filter for sales by date? Table 1 has date and invoice Table 2 has invoice and sales

Tags: sql, crystal-reports

I am trying to build a crystal report summing sales for the month.  One table called **header** table has the Invoice Date (`inv_date`) and invoice number (`inv_num`).  The other table has the sale dollars (`Lin_tot`) and invoice number (`inv_num`).  The `inv_num` are linked.  How can I use the date effectively to sort for sales.

To make things slightly more complicated the `inv_date` (`yyyymmdd`) is not formatted properly so I generally need to use a formula to correct this in order to use the current month function.  I am not sure if this is playing a role for the date filtering.

What I do Know:
How to sum the sales and filter for current month

What I don't know:
How to use the date from the one table in relation to inventory number.  In Excel I could use a `vlookup` on `inv_num` to pull the date and artificially make a column.

[image: tables]

Answer (score 0):

Joining headers and lines this way produces a result set containing columns from both tables, where header columns' content is repeated for every belonging line of course. So you can just use the header field `inv_date` to filter sales numbers by date.

Using a formula that converts the `inv_date` value to a date data type within the filter condition will work, too. But it could lead to poor performance, because filtering probably cannot be delegated to the data source any more then. (In this case Crystal Reports would retrieve all data lines and do the filtering on client side.)

Comment: Thank you for this.  I cleared all links and just went with Inv_num and it seemed to clear up a lot of the issues for me.